# A “puck” of frozen food

Tags: language, measurements

I found a recipe that calls for 5 “pucks” of frozen spinach. I cannot find a definition of the term. I need to know how many ounces are in a puck?

Comment: I suspect that this is going to be like measurements in "cans" -- although there might be a standard, it's going to be dependent on the time, region, and possibly even context.  (in the case of "cans", those for home sales vs. industrial sizes like a #10 can)

Comment: do you have a link to the recipe or reference to the recipe you are using ? it'll make answering the question easier.

Answer (score 5):

The term "puck" is not in general use for food, but it seems to refer to a hockey puck-like volume of frozen spinach. (Spinach is commonly found frozen into blocks.) Presumably the author of the recipe had a particular brand - and therefore size standard - of spinach in mind. The spinach "pucks" in my freezer are about 4 oz each, but other sizes are also common.

Find a better recipe, or ask the author for clarification.

Comment: Just to show how different the "pucks" can be: The ones in my freezer right now weigh about 20 grams each.

Comment: Yup, the 2 brands I get most frequently are possibly a factor of 2 or 3 different in 'puck' size. You really need a weight, not a count, for something like that.

Comment: Having  never heard of a puck of spinach (in the US, I have seen them sold frozen in a small box shape- like the size of a paperback novel maybe), I searched online and found many ways to make your own pucks. But even there the size varies by what you make it in- ice cube tray to cupcake (muffin) tin. I agree that the cupcake would be closest to a hockey puck. Note I am not saying a cupcake is a muffin, just the tins are used for both.